# Expression of type: 'Int' does not match the field: 'value'

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to get a variable to get the length of an array with the following,

```
@length(activity('My JSON Array').output)
```

But getting the error,

```
Expression of type: 'Int' does not match the field: 'value'
```

Comment: after which activity you are using this? and at which activity you are trying to get this value? could you please add this information.

Comment: Thanks RakeshGovindula-MT, I'm copying data from a JSON array, the goal is to get the size of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@length()` function returns integer value. But the variables in data factory only supports **String, Boolean, Array**.


[image]


That's why it is showing error like that.


[image]


So, to store length of the array in a variable in ADF, first convert it to string.

```
@string(length(activity('JSON array').output.value))
```

Here my output array comes from a lookup. That's why I have used `.value`.

[image]


When you want use this value, just convert it to int at the time of usage with `int()`.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful! Unfortunately I was wrong, what I thought was a JSON array is an object so the length() is now the issue.